# .csv Keep only certain email addresses?

Tags: sed, awk, csv-simple

I have a large .csv file with my customers Name:Email

I have another large list of emails that are part of this list and only want to keep those. How can I remove all contacts from the .csv file that are not in X.txt?

Comment: Expand your post and put a few lines of your originial of your file and put target file(removed some fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the email to be in a particular field of the .csv file, and only need to print those lines of the file that contain one of the target emails, you could just use `grep`:

```
grep -wFf emails.txt file.csv > newfile.csv
```

If they do need to be in a specific field, use @ChrisDown's [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204121/22222). Note, however, that csv files can be quite complex. For example, this is a valid csv line:

```
field1,"field 2, which can contain commas, is here", field3
```

For such, more complex files, you will need to use a csv parser to deal with them correctly. For example, in Perl, you can use `Text::CSV`:

1. Install `cpanm` (if you use Perl, you'll thank me later)

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install cpanminus
   ```

   If you're not on a Debian based system, you should be able to install it using your distribution's package manager.
2. Install the `Text::CSV` module

   ```
   $ sudo cpanm Text::CSV
   ```
3. Parse your file

   ```
   $ perl -MText::CSV -le '

       BEGIN{
           open($f,"emails.txt"); 
           while(<$f>){chomp; $k{$_}++;}
       } 
       $csv=Text::CSV->new({binary=>1}); 
       while ($row = $csv->getline(STDIN)){
         print join",", @$row if defined($k{$row->[2]})
       }' < file.csv
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the e-mails in X.txt are one per line, you can build an array, check it for existence, and then print out the matching lines:

```
$ awk -F: 'FNR==NR { a[$2] = $0; next } ($1 in a) { print a[$1] }' customers.csv X.txt
Foo Bar:foo@bar.com
Baz Qux:baz@qux.com
```

`FNR==NR` will only be true when in the first file. Here are the files I used to test this:

```
$ cat customers.csv 
Foo Bar:foo@bar.com
Baz Qux:baz@qux.com
Wibble Wobble:wibble@wobble.com
```

```
$ cat X.txt 
foo@bar.com
baz@qux.com
```